# How to find contradiction in order of items in multiple sequences

Tags: c#, algorithm, linq

Suppose you have several sequences:

```
  A: 1  2  3  4  5
  B: 2  4  5
  C: 2  1  3  4  5
  D: 3  2
```

Here, some pairs of list contradicts each other, because they don't expose the same order for their similar elements: (A,C) (A,D) (C, D)

What is an algorithm or a linq statements to find such pairs? Or just to say if my sequences have such a contradiction or not! I store these sequences in a list of lists of strings

```
 List<List<String>> Sequences;
```

This is my code for the problem:

```
    private bool HasContradiction(List<List<String>> Sequences)
    {
        Cont = new List<Tuple<string, string>>();
        bool f = false;
        foreach (List<String> item1 in Sequences)
        {

            foreach (string elem1 in item1)
            {
                foreach (string elem2 in item1)
                {
                    int o1 = GetIndexOrder(item1, elem1, elem2);
                    foreach (List<String> item2 in Sequences)
                    {
                        int o2 = GetIndexOrder(item2, elem1, elem2);
                        if (o2 != 0 && o2 != o1)
                        {
                            Cont.Add(new Tuple<string, string>(String.Join(" ", item1), String.Join(" ", item2)));
                            f = true;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return f;
    }
    // this list stores contradicted pairs
    List<Tuple<string, string>> Cont = new List<Tuple<string, string>>();
    private int GetIndexOrder(List<string> item, string elem1, string elem2)
    {
        int i = item.FindIndex(x => x == elem1);
        int j = item.FindIndex(x => x == elem2);
        if (i < 0 || j < 0)
        {
            return 0;
        }
        if (i <= j)
        {
            return 1;
        }

        return 2;

    }
```

To test it:

```
    List<List<String>> seqs = new List<List<String>>{
    new List<String>{
        "1", "2", "3", "4", "5"
    },
    new List<String>{
         "2", "4", "5"
    },
    new List<String>{
        "2", "1","3","4","5"
    },
    new List<String>{
        "3", "2"
    },

};


        HasContradiction(seqs);
        foreach (var item in Cont.Distinct())
        {
            string tt = item.Item1 + "   AND  " + item.Item2;

            listView2.Items.Add(tt);
        }
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Does your code produce the expected results ?

Comment: @Heslacher yes, I see the contradiction in the resulted pairs, however I am not sure they are all the pairs possible.

Comment: I think it is flawed. I tested it and I never got (B,C) nor (B,D) which if I understand the problem should be found as well.

Comment: @Heslacher as I tested it, it works, please check the update

Comment: So should (B,C) and (B,D)  be found ?

Comment: @Heslacher no because by that logic you'd also be missing (A, B), and might as well match any list which is not a direct sublist (which is not the problem statement here). You'd have total (A,B) (A,C) (A,D), (B, C) (B, D), (C, D) as contradictions, which would also be all combinations.

Comment: @Heslacher No, (B,C) and (B,D) don't contradict each other, because the elements in both of them are in the same order.

Comment: Sorry, it seems I didn't understand the problem statement correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the case

```
A: 1 2 3 2 4 5
B: 1 2 2 4 5
C: 3 2 
D: 2 3
E: 2 2
F: 1 2 3 4 5
```

You report back:

```
1 2 3 2 4 5 contradicts 3 2 
1 2 3 2 4 5 contradicts 3 2
1 2 3 2 4 5 contradicts 3 2
1 2 3 2 4 5 contradicts 3 2 
3 2 contradicts 1 2 3 2 4 5
3 2 contradicts 2 3
3 2 contradicts 1 2 3 4 5 
3 2 contradicts 1 2 3 2 4 5
3 2 contradicts 2 3
3 2 contradicts 1 2 3 4 5
2 3 contradicts 3 2      
2 3 contradicts 3 2      
1 2 3 4 5 contradicts 3 2
1 2 3 4 5 contradicts 3 2
```

I used this code to test: ( http://goo.gl/QOEBao or http://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_csharp_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMZGNRVXQ2Y0JlOU0 )

```
static void Main()
{
    List<List<String>> seqs = new List<List<String>>{
        new List<String>{
            "1", "2", "3", "2", "4", "5"
        },
        new List<String>{
            "1", "2", "2", "4", "5"
        },
        new List<String>{
            "3", "2"
        },
        new List<String>{
            "2", "3"
        },
        new List<String>{
            "2", "2"
        },
        new List<String>{
            "1", "2", "3", "4", "5"
        }
    };
    if (HasContradiction(seqs))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("yep");
        foreach(Tuple<string, string> x in Cont)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(x.Item1 + " contradicts "+ x.Item2);
        }
    } else {
        Console.WriteLine("nope");
    }
}
```

There's a few that are not correct - if I label them...

```
X 1 2 3 2 4 5 contradicts 3 2 
X 1 2 3 2 4 5 contradicts 3 2
X 1 2 3 2 4 5 contradicts 3 2
X 1 2 3 2 4 5 contradicts 3 2 
X 3 2 contradicts 1 2 3 2 4 5
Y 3 2 contradicts 2 3
Y 3 2 contradicts 1 2 3 4 5 
X 3 2 contradicts 1 2 3 2 4 5
Y 3 2 contradicts 2 3
Y 3 2 contradicts 1 2 3 4 5
Y 2 3 contradicts 3 2      
Y 2 3 contradicts 3 2      
Y 1 2 3 4 5 contradicts 3 2
Y 1 2 3 4 5 contradicts 3 2
```

Then these are wrong:

```
X 1 2 3 2 4 5 contradicts 3 2 
X 1 2 3 2 4 5 contradicts 3 2
X 1 2 3 2 4 5 contradicts 3 2
X 1 2 3 2 4 5 contradicts 3 2 
X 3 2 contradicts 1 2 3 2 4 5
X 3 2 contradicts 1 2 3 2 4 5
```

Basically, what you don't do is check for duplicates.

Now, there's two things this could mean:

First option, you don't actually support duplicates. It's logically impossible for there to be duplicates. In that case, you should take an ordered, unique collection as input (a sorted set, as it were). A weaker alternative might be checking if you have duplicates and throwing errors for that, if altering the signature is not possible.

Second option, you do support duplicates. In that case, you should alter your code to support duplicates.

Comment: Why wrong? they contradicts each other, for example in `1 2 3 2 4 5`, 3 follows 2 but in `3 2`, 2 follows 3. However it seems using two 2 makes the first list contradict itself.

Comment: Because lets say this is music, "hit the notes like A B C B D E" and you ask "does it contain a C and then a B" the answer should be "yes it does" and you say "no, because there is a B in front of the C"

Comment: Now I got what you say, I think I don't support duplicates and I count those listed above as contradictions.

Comment: @Ahmad Then first option it is; you shouldn't take list, but some other collection instead that cannot contain duplicates, but does have an order. Like SortedSet.

Answer (score 0):

[This CodeReview Question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/119519/regex-to-first-match-then-replace-found-matches) hints at an answer.

I.E. Create a `RegEx` of one string, matching to the others in turn. A non-empty `MatchCollection` of course means there is no "contradiction". And `Match.Index` tells you where a match is made.